# How to split a list of objects to separate columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in dataframe as list of objects(Array of structs) like

```
column: [{key1:value1}, {key2:value2}, {key3:value3}]
```

I want to split this column into separate columns with key name as column name and value as column value in same row.
Final result like

```
key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3
```

How to achieve this in pyspark ?

E.g.

Sample data to create dataframe:

```
my_new_schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', LongType()),
    StructField('countries', ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField('name', StringType()),
        StructField('capital', StringType())
    ])))
])
l = [(1, [
        {'name': 'Italy', 'capital': 'Rome'},
        {'name': 'Spain', 'capital': 'Madrid'}
    ])
]
    
dz = spark.createDataFrame(l, schema=my_new_schema)
# we have array of structs:
dz.show(truncate=False)
+---+--------------------------------+
|id |countries                       |
+---+--------------------------------+
|1  |[{Italy, Rome}, {Spain, Madrid}]|
+---+--------------------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+--------+---------+
|id |Italy   |  Spain  |
+---+------------------+
|1  |Rome    | Madrid  |
+---+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) the `countries` array then pivot the country `name` column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dz1 = dz.selectExpr(
    "id", 
    "inline(countries)"
).groupBy("id").pivot("name").agg(
    F.first("capital")
)

dz1.show()
#+---+-----+------+
#|id |Italy|Spain |
#+---+-----+------+
#|1  |Rome |Madrid|
#+---+-----+------+
```

Comment: is it possible to do pivot on condition.. let's say if the struct has another property continent:Europe, i want to pivot the country name and capital as earlier but only if the continent value is Europe.. is this possible to do

Comment: @Manojkumar simply add a filter before grouping: `dz1 = dz.selectExpr("id", "inline(countries)").filter("continent = 'Europe'")...`